# How to add field to association table

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am making a drink database with two tables `Drink` and `Ingredient`. Additionally there is an association table `DrinkIngredients` that connects these two so i can search which drinks contain a specific ingredient as well as which ingredients make up a certain drink.

Problem is that different drinks require different amounts of ingredients. So if I have two drinks, for example a `Screwdriver` which has `Vodka` and `Orange Juice` in the association table for it, as well as `Tequila Sunrise` which has `Tequila` an `Orange Juice` in the association table. I want to be able to do a query for Screwdriver and then query `Screwdriver.Ingredients` and get a list like

`Vodka: 1 unit`
`Orange Juice: 1 unit`

but then also query `TequilaSunrise.Ingredients` and get

`Tequila: 1 unit`
`Orange Juice: 2 units`

How do i go about adding additional information to the association table? or do i need to add a entirely new association table thats a subtable of the association table i already have for the amounts?

[Here is a link to my models.py file](http://pastebin.com/eLas86VX)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, just add a new column to Drinkingredient table with quantity

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that,  would it just be a third line `db.Column('amount', db.Integer)` to the association table? If so how do I access it?